# update_post_meta not working, but values are true

Tags: php

I want to update posts in frontend in my Wordpress site. BUt update_post_meta doesnt work, I tested datas with echo, but they are working very well.

```
if(isset($_POST['save_button'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {

        echo 'Error';

    } else {

        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        update_post_meta($post_id,'post_title', $_POST['title']);

        echo $post_id; // works good;
        echo $_POST['title']; //works good;

        echo 'Saved';

    }

}
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working - the data isn't getting saved, or you see the same data before and after updating the meta data? But if you're actually trying to update the post title, then you can use functions like `wp_update_post()`.

Comment: Yes, these codes dont change anything. Thanks for helping Sally. I searched on Google about wp_update_post and now it is working. For wp_posts I had to wp_update_post function.

Comment: Yes that's correct, because post titles are not metadata (or custom fields) which are saved in the `wp_postmeta` table. Post titles are instead main post data saved in the `wp_posts` table, so post meta functions like `update_post_meta()` won't update data (post title/content/etc.) in the `wp_posts` table.